# After successful login page not found 404 encountered, when setting 'pageNotFound_handling' TYPO3 7.6 version

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-404

If my successful login redirected url is like

domain.com/abc/xyz

where 
abc = my page name

xyz = my action name of my custom extension

404 = 404 page name

When I set 404 page as below;

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] =  404
```

Then after successful login its redirected to 404 error page, it should redirect as earlier ie. domain.com/abc/xyz not 404 page

Comment: do you have .htaccess file active ? You may have not realurl or htaccess file active ( active means to remove underscore befor dot _.htaccess -> .htaccess ).

Answer (score 0):

It's redirects to 404 page, because may be your url `domain.com/abc/xyz` is not found on your domain.

You can select `After Successful Login Redirect to Page` option in `login form plugin` with page `abc` and your custom extension plugin is used on this page(abc).